# How can get a part of a 2D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d array with shape (100, 64).
I need to obtain a new array like (100, 63), just like deleting one column from a sheet.
So what numpy function should I use to obtain this?

```
# Let X be my (100, 64) dataset, and i the column I want to delete
np.somefunction(X[:, :i], X[:, i:])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `delete`:

```
np.delete(X, i, axis=1)
```

or `hstack`:

```
np.hstack((X[:, :i-1], X[:, i:])
```